# Datatable js in angular object destroy and data refresh not happening

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, datatables, angular-datatables

we are using datatablejs plugin of angular for listing data in our project https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started ; there are certain events where the data needs to be refreshed in the datalist.

this is working with datatable js on jquery where we destroy and reload it with service.

with angular the data is not changing unless any column is clicked or page is reloaded, which is a problem for us.

how can this be resolved.

we dont wish to move to material table as there are many component where this needs to be fixed.

html:

```
   <!-- For tabs changes -->
                  <mat-tab-group>
                    <mat-tab label="Draft">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><br />

                          <table datatable [dtOptions]="draftdtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
                            class="mahait-table row-border hover">
                            <thead class="dt-head-center">


                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="dt-body-center">
                              <tr *ngFor="let createCal of createCals let row">
                                <td>
                                  <button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-info btn-sm reject-button-alignment m-btn-body mt-1"
                                    style="margin-top:1px"
                                    (click)="open(row,$event,modal_edit_academic_calen_details)">Edit</button>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger reject-button-alignment mt-1"
                                    style="margin-left:5px;" (click)="openDelete(row,$event)">Delete</button><br />

                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-update  reject-button-alignment mb-1"
                                    style="margin-top:4px"
                                    (click)="someClickHandler(row,$event,modal_update_event_details)">Update
                                    Events</button>

                                  <button type="button" (click)=openSendApprove(row,$event,modal_action_details)
                                    class="btn btn-success reject-button-alignment mb-1"
                                    style="margin-top:3px; margin-left:5px;">Send
                                    for
                                    Apporval</button>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ createCal.AcademicYear }}</td>
                                <td> <a style="color:blue; cursor: pointer;"
                                    (click)="openView(row,$event,modal_view_academic_calen_details)">{{ createCal.CalendarCode }}</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ createCal.EventCount }}</td>
                                <td>{{ createCal.CalandarType }}</td>
                                <td>{{ createCal.calendar_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ createCal.created_on | date :  'yyyy-MM-dd'  }}</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>

                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </mat-tab>
                    <mat-tab label="Send for Approval">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><br />


                          <table id="second-table" datatable [dtOptions]="SendApproveldtOptions"
                            class="mahait-table row-border hover">
                            <thead class="dt-head-center"></thead>
                            <tbody class="dt-body-center">

                              <tr *ngFor="let sendTable of sendTables let row">


                                <td>{{  sendTable.AcademicYear }}</td>
                                <td><a style="color:blue; cursor: pointer;"
                                    (click)="openView(row,$event,modal_view_academic_calen_details)">{{ sendTable.CalendarCode }}</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{  sendTable.EventCount }}</td>
                                <td>{{  sendTable.CalandarType }}</td>
                                <td>{{  sendTable.calendar_name }}</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>

                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </mat-tab>

                  </mat-tab-group>
                   <!-- End tabs changes -->
```

ts:

```
// code starts here
            import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'; // Data Table 
            import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
            import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
            import { AcmServiceService } from '../../Shared/acm-service.service';
            import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
            import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
            import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
            import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
            import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
            import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables'; // Data Table 
            import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
            import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
            import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
            import { RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';
            import { Router } from '@angular/router';


            class DataTablesResponse {
            data: any[];
            draw: number;
            recordsFiltered: number;
            recordsTotal: number;
            }

            class createCal {
            AcademicYear: any;
            CalendarCode: any;
            EventCount: any;
            CalandarType: any;
            calendar_name: any;
            created_o_n: any;

            }


            class sendTable {
            AcademicYear: any;
            CalendarCode: any;
            EventCount: any;
            CalandarType: any;
            calendar_name: any;


            }
            export class AcmManageAcademicCalendarComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {

            @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)  // Data Table
            dtElement: DataTableDirective; // Data Table

            draftdtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};    // First Data Table
            SendApproveldtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {}; // Second Data Table

            dtTrigger: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();     // First Data Table Trigger 

            dtTrigger2: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();    // Second Data Table Trigger 

            userData = { organisation_id: '1', requestStatusID: '1' };
            userData1 = { organisation_id: '1', requestStatusID: '2' };

            constructor(private Service: AcmServiceService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
            }
            ngOnInit() {
            this.dataTableAngulr();
            this.sendTabale();
            }

            //  FIrst Data Table Call 
            dataTableAngulr() {
            const that = this;

            this.draftdtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 4,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            search: true,

            ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
            that.http
            .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'http://fakeapiorg/api/acm/CalendarList', Object.assign(dataTablesParameters, this.userData), {}
            ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.createCals = resp.data;

            callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
            data: []

            });
            });

            },
            columns: [
            { data: '', title: 'Action', name: 'ay.academic_start_year' },
            { data: 'AcademicYear', title: 'Academic Year', name: 'academic_start_year' },
            { data: 'CalendarCode', title: 'Calendar ID', name: 'calendar_id' },
            { data: 'EventCount', title: 'Events Count', name: 'EventCount' },
            { data: 'CalandarType', title: 'Academic Calendar Type', name: 'ct.taxonomy_name' },
            { data: 'calendar_name', title: 'Calendar Name', name: 'ac.calendar_name' },
            { data: 'created_on', title: 'Modified Date', name: 'ac.created_on' }

            ],

            };
            }
            ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            this.dtTrigger.next();
            this.dtTrigger2.next();
            }

            ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
            this.dtTrigger2.unsubscribe();
            }

            rerender(): void {
            this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {

            dtInstance.destroy();
            this.dtTrigger.next();
            this.dtTrigger2.next();  // Second Table call for rerender
            });
            }


            //  Second Data Table 

            sendTabale() {
            const that = this;

            this.SendApproveldtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 4,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            search: true,

            ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
            that.http
            .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'http://fakeapiorg/api/acm/CalendarList', Object.assign(dataTablesParameters, this.userData1), {}
            ).subscribe(resp => {

            that.sendTables = resp.data;

            callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
            data: []

            });
            });

            },
            columns: [
            { data: 'AcademicYear', title: 'Academic Year', name: 'academic_start_year' },
            { data: 'CalendarCode', title: 'Calendar ID', name: 'calendar_id' },
            { data: 'EventCount', title: 'Events Count', name: 'EventCount' },
            { data: 'CalandarType', title: 'Academic Calendar Type', name: 'ct.taxonomy_name' },
            { data: 'calendar_name', title: 'Calendar Name', name: 'ac.calendar_name' }
            ]
            };
            }


            }

            Send_Approve_Adademic() {
            this.sendApproveObj = {
            RequestID: this.request_id,
            RequestStatusID: '2'
            }

            this.Service.create('AcademicCalandarStatusChange', this.sendApproveObj).subscribe(res => {
            if (res['status'] == true) {
            Swal.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: ' Successfully Send Approvel',
            onClose: () => {
            this.GetAPI();

            this.modalRef3.close();
            }
            })
            }
            this.rerender(); // call The Rerender table
            })
            }
// code ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a change detection issue. You might need to manually detect the changes that your API call is making.

Replace your component code with below:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; // Data Table 
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { AcmServiceService } from '../../Shared/acm-service.service';
import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables'; // Data Table 
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


class DataTablesResponse {
    data: any[];
    draw: number;
    recordsFiltered: number;
    recordsTotal: number;
}

class createCal {
    AcademicYear: any;
    CalendarCode: any;
    EventCount: any;
    CalandarType: any;
    calendar_name: any;
    created_o_n: any;

}


class sendTable {
    AcademicYear: any;
    CalendarCode: any;
    EventCount: any;
    CalandarType: any;
    calendar_name: any;


}
export class AcmManageAcademicCalendarComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {

    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)  // Data Table
    dtElement: DataTableDirective; // Data Table

    draftdtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};    // First Data Table
    SendApproveldtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {}; // Second Data Table

    dtTrigger: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();     // First Data Table Trigger 

    dtTrigger2: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();    // Second Data Table Trigger 

    userData = { organisation_id: '1', requestStatusID: '1' };
    userData1 = { organisation_id: '1', requestStatusID: '2' };

    constructor(private Service: AcmServiceService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router,
    private cdREf: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataTableAngulr();
        this.sendTabale();
    }

    //  FIrst Data Table Call 
    dataTableAngulr() {
        const that = this;

        this.draftdtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 4,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            search: true,

            ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
                that.http
                    .post<DataTablesResponse>(
                        'http://fakeapiorg/api/acm/CalendarList', Object.assign(dataTablesParameters, this.userData), {}
                    ).subscribe(resp => {
                        that.createCals = resp.data;

                        callback({
                            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
                            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
                            data: []

                        });

                        this.cdREf.markForCheck();
                    });

            },
            columns: [
                { data: '', title: 'Action', name: 'ay.academic_start_year' },
                { data: 'AcademicYear', title: 'Academic Year', name: 'academic_start_year' },
                { data: 'CalendarCode', title: 'Calendar ID', name: 'calendar_id' },
                { data: 'EventCount', title: 'Events Count', name: 'EventCount' },
                { data: 'CalandarType', title: 'Academic Calendar Type', name: 'ct.taxonomy_name' },
                { data: 'calendar_name', title: 'Calendar Name', name: 'ac.calendar_name' },
                { data: 'created_on', title: 'Modified Date', name: 'ac.created_on' }

            ],

        };
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.dtTrigger.next();
        this.dtTrigger2.next();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
        this.dtTrigger2.unsubscribe();
    }

    rerender(): void {
        this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {

            dtInstance.destroy();
            this.dtTrigger.next();
            this.dtTrigger2.next();  // Second Table call for rerender
        });
    }


    //  Second Data Table 

    sendTabale() {
        const that = this;

        this.SendApproveldtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 4,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            search: true,

            ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
                that.http
                    .post<DataTablesResponse>(
                        'http://fakeapiorg/api/acm/CalendarList', Object.assign(dataTablesParameters, this.userData1), {}
                    ).subscribe(resp => {

                        that.sendTables = resp.data;

                        callback({
                            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
                            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
                            data: []

                        });
                        this.cdREf.markForCheck();
                    });

            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'AcademicYear', title: 'Academic Year', name: 'academic_start_year' },
                { data: 'CalendarCode', title: 'Calendar ID', name: 'calendar_id' },
                { data: 'EventCount', title: 'Events Count', name: 'EventCount' },
                { data: 'CalandarType', title: 'Academic Calendar Type', name: 'ct.taxonomy_name' },
                { data: 'calendar_name', title: 'Calendar Name', name: 'ac.calendar_name' }
            ]
        };
    }


}

Send_Approve_Adademic() {
    this.sendApproveObj = {
        RequestID: this.request_id,
        RequestStatusID: '2'
    }

    this.Service.create('AcademicCalandarStatusChange', this.sendApproveObj).subscribe(res => {
        if (res['status'] == true) {
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: ' Successfully Send Approvel',
                onClose: () => {
                    this.GetAPI();

                    this.modalRef3.close();
                }
            })
        }
        this.rerender(); // call The Rerender table
    })
}
```

Comment: we tried this but its not working, is there something else which can be done ?